# How to import Nuxt modules inside a js file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

What I'm trying to do is to import Nuxt modules inside a js file.
for example I want to use "@nuxt/axios" inside a js file and create an instance from it and I don't want to call it from context object I want to make that instance separate from any Nuxt life cycle and also use the nuxt axios modules not the normal axios package.

```
import axios from "@nuxt/axios"

const axiosInstace = axios.create();

export default axiosInstace;
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use these modules directly. `@nuxt/axios` is just a wrapper for the `axios` module. Just use that instead ([NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)). Same goes for most other nuxt modules.

Comment: Look what I'm trying to create is to make the baseURL in axios to be the same as the  domain with some prefixes or in other words to more dynamic, and that happens if I have the context object, I need I way to create the same functionally without the context object

Answer (score 1):

Just like what @Florian Pallas mentioned. Don't use these modules. use NPM or/and extend Axios from [plugins](https://axios.nuxtjs.org/extend/)

Edited answer:
I remember seeing this code somewhere

```
const myAPI = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://api.domaine.com/',
  withCredentials: false,
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  params: {
    order: 'desc',
    sort: 'name'
  }
})

function request(id) {
    myAPI.get('/users/'+id);
}

request(123)
```

Comment: Look what I'm trying to create is to make the baseURL in axios to be the same as the  domain with some prefixes or in other words to more dynamic, and that happens if I have the context object, I need I way to create the same functionally without the context object

Comment: check my answer

Comment: in my case, the baseURL is depending on the domain because I try to create a saas project so I cant set the baseURL directly, I want to prefix it. I tried to create that functionality in "@nuxt/axios" because "@nuxt/axios" has a function "onRequest" this function like "axios interceptors.request" on this function there is common object and inside of it there is the sented domain, but this only happens in "@nuxt/axios" not in normal "axios", that why I need to import this package to use it in different files without context object, or in normal axios prefix the domain in some way to be dynamic.

Comment: Have you tried this package? https://github.com/srph/axios-base-url

Comment: I think this package will help me because If you're using axios >=v0.8, please use the base url configuration provided by the library out of the box.